# Add a vector to all columns of a matrix with ArrayFire

Tags: matrix, vector, addition, arrayfire

What is the best way to add a vector to all columns of a Matrix with ArrayFire?

At the moment i'm using a `gfor` loop, but that seems wrong for such a simple task.

```
gfor(af::seq i, M.dims(1)) {
    M(af::span, i) += VECTOR;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tile`. Since you are tiling a singleton dimension (VECTOR.dims(1) = 1), this will be done as a JIT operation (in the same kernel) and not call a different kernel.

```
M += af::tile(VECTOR, 1, M.dims(1));
```